# Parts of Speech and Grammar Point for -ing

Tags: syntactic-analysis, ing

Can someone help me to explain the two following structures — identifying parts of speech, and in particular why we’re using the *-ing* form of *have* in the first?

1. How about having lunch?
2. Why don't we go for lunch?

Comment: (1) has a gerund _having lunch_, shortened from _us having lunch_; _how about_ is an idiom that suggests a joint activity: _How about taking a walk or reading a book after lunch?_ (2) is a negative question, and _Why don't we_ is an idiom similar to _how about_ in its pragmatic sense.

Comment: Hi John, why not post this as an answer, so that I can upvote it, and mark it as correct?

Comment: @John The context (with the “Why don't we” question right next to it) indicates it is so here, but why does “how about having” have to be shortened at all? The sentence could be ‘shortened’ from a number of other things; but I find it much easier to just think of it as not being shortened at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would explain "How about having lunch?" as shortened from

How (do you think) about having lunch?

Here "having" is gerund. After a preposition such as "about" follows a noun or a
gerund which is the noun-form of a verb.

Comment: To speak of a gerund being **“the”** noun form of a verb is to forget the other obvious noun form of a verb.

Comment: I disagree.  The response to *How do you think about having lunch?* would be *With my brain!*

Comment: @Anonym - What is your explanation for the shortened formula "How about doing something"?

Comment: _How about `X`?_ is an idiom asking for opinions about `X`. Where `X` is _(having) lunch_, it's an invitation to (have) lunch (together, unless otherwise specified).